# How to send files created in a mobile app without overwritten the name in the server when the app is used by different users

Tags: react-native, file, multipartform-data, fastapi

I am working in a mobile app. In this mobile app I need to send a file (.wav file) to a server.

At this moment, I am working locally and testing my app. I am creating an audio file in the mobile app with a defined name and extension. However, I'm wondering, If my app is used by more people,

can it happen that, if the different users use the app and send the file *at the same time*, as the file name is already defined in the app, *in the server this file is going to be overwitten* ?

What is usually the behaviour in a situation like this? And if the file is overwitten, how can I overcome this problem, since diffrent users may send a different file?

Details:

- API : FAST API :

async def something(file: UploadFile = File(...)):

```
with open(f"{file.filename}", "wb") as buffer:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
```

#saved teh file

- developing with React NAtive
- Using Expo AV to do the audio
- sending the audio using fetch
- sending method:

formData.append("file",
uri: path,
name: "audio.wav",
type: "audio/wav",

....

method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
},
body: formData,

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This scenario should be handled completely by the server. The client should not contain any logic on what files are already located on the server and which are not.

Let the server create a new `uuid` for each new file that it receives.

Thus, the metadata for a file upload could be the following object.

```js
{
   uuid: "11edc52b-2918-4d71-9058-f7285e29d894",
   fileUri: "",
}
```

Thus, the server needs to be adapted to solve this problem. The file is then stored along with its unique identifier. No name clash should occur.

Of course, if you want to display the files in the client later, then you need some name property, which could be the fileUri appended with a counter variable if the same fileUri exists multiple times. This should be handled by the server as well.

Comment: Do not trust uuids created by the client; always create the uuid (if required; you can probably just use the autoincrement key from your database) and check for collisions yourself.

Comment: I agree, this is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, so when I receive a file from the client I should rename it in the server side /API to be sure that this wont collide with other files ? 
Thanks for your answer, I just didn't know How servers behave, so I wasn't sure this would be a problem... I suspected though.

Comment: I wouldn't rename the actual file, but use an additional uuid. But, I mean if you do not have control over the server, then this discussion is not really helpful. In this case I don't think that there is much that you can do.